# OCaml - Accumulator Using Fold Left

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

Learning OCaml from [here](https://try.ocamlpro.com/).

I want to verify if I have understood how this snippet of OCaml code works

```
List.fold_left (fun acc x -> acc + x) 0 [ 1; 2; 3; 4 ]
```

I have an intuition that this is an equivalent to the `reduce` function in Python. Specifically, I think it is equivalent to

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, [1, 2, 3])
```

The anonymous function is taking two parameters - `acc` and `x` and returns a single value `acc + x`. I understand that initially, the first argument `acc` will be 0 but how does it know that the second argument has to be the first element of the list?

What I think is happening is that `fold_left` provides the two arguments to the anonymous function and then recursively calls itself with new arguments until the list becomes empty.

To confirm this I saw [this](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html).

When I define a function like `let inc x = x + 1` I get something like `val inc : int -> int = <fun>` but in this case the signature is `: ('a -> 'b -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'b list -> 'a = <fun>`

What is `'a` and how should I interpret this function signature so that `List.fold_right f [a1; ...; an] b` becomes `f a1 (f a2 (... (f an b) ...))`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are asking many questions.

I'm pretty sure that Python `reduce` is a fold, so your intuition is probably right.

You ask "how does it know that the second argument has to be the first element of the list?" Unfortunately, I don't think this is a well formed question. There's no "it" that knows anything. Most likely the answer is given by the definition of `fold_left`. It knows what to do because somebody wrote the code that way :-)

Here is the definition of `fold_left` from the standard library:

```
let rec fold_left f accu l =
  match l with
    [] -> accu
  | a::l -> fold_left f (f accu a) l
```

In some sense, this should answer all your questions.

The type `'a` in the type of `fold_left` is the type of the accumulator. The point is that you can use any type you want for the accumulator. This is why the fold is so powerful. As long as it matches the values accepted and returned by the folded function, it can be anything you want.

Comment: So when does OCaml know that a parameter of a function is `'a` or an `int`?

Comment: Short answer: the key theorem for Hindley-Milner typing says that any function parameter or type parameter you can't figure out a type for (with important restrictions) is a polymorphic parameter. There's some explanation here: [OCaml Type Inference](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/basics.html#Typeinference) and here [Hindley-Milner Type System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley–Milner_type_system)

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, reduce is a simpler version of fold, which takes the first element of the list as starting element. I'd define it this way:

```
let reduce f = function 
   | x::xs -> fold_left f x xs
   | [] -> failwith "can't call reduce on empty lists!"
```

If you enter it in OCaml, it will display its type:

```
val reduce : ('a -> 'a -> 'a) -> 'a list -> 'a
```

You can contrast it with fold_left's type:

```
('b -> 'a -> 'b) -> 'b -> 'a list -> 'b
```

The type variables `'a` and `'b` here mean that they can stand for any type. In your example, both `'a` and `'b` become `int`. If we insert the types, `fold_left` has the signature:

```
(int -> int -> int) -> int -> int list -> int
```

That's what we expected: `+` is a function which takes two ints and returns a new one, `0` is an int and the `[1;2;3;4;]` is a list of ints. The case that `fold_left` has two type variables and `reduce` only has one already gives a hint that it is more general. To see why we can look at the definition of `reduce`. Since the starting element of the fold is an element of the list, the types `'a'` and `'b` must be the same. That's fine for summing up elements, but say, we'd like to construct an abstract syntax tree for our summation. We define a type for this:

```
type exp = Plus of exp * exp | Number of int
```

Then we can call:

```
fold_left (fun x y -> Plus (x, (Number y))) (Number 0) [1; 2; 3; 4]
```

Which results in the expression:

```
Plus (Plus (Plus (Plus (Number 0, Number 1), Number 2), Number 3), Number 4)
```

A benefit of this tree is that you can nicely see what is applied first (0 and 1) - in case of addition this is not a problem, since it is associative (this means a+(b+c) = (a+b)+c) which is not the case for subtraction (compare e.g. 5-(3-2) and (5-3)-2).

If you want to do something similar with reduce, you will notice that OCaml complains about type errors:

`reduce (fun x y -> Plus (x, (Number y))) [1; 2; 3; 4] ;;
Error: This expression has type exp but an expression was expected of type

int`

In this case, we can wrap each integer as an expression in our input list, then the types agree. Since we already have Numbers, we don't need to add the Number constructor to y:

```
let wrapped = map (fun x -> Number x) [1; 2; 3; 4] in
reduce (fun x y -> Plus (x, y)) wrapped
```

Again, we have the same result, but we needed an additional function call to `map`. In the case of `fold_left`, this is not necessary.

P.S.: You might have noticed that OCaml gives the type of fold_left as `('a -> 'b -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'b list -> 'a`. I guess you will quickly realize that the name of the type variables doesn't play a role. To make it easier to compare, I switched the names such that the function is always applied to a list of `'a`.

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but the comparison between OCaml's folds and Python's [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) may be easier if you incorporate `reduce`'s `initializer` argument.

Summing a list of ints in OCaml using a fold:

```ml
let sum = List.fold_left (+) 0 [1; 2; 3]
```

And using `reduce` in Python.

```
from functools import reduce

sum = reduce(int.__add__, [1, 2, 3], 0)
```

Here you can see the order of arguments is a bit different, but they're all there.

Python feels it's less likely you'll need the initializer, so leaves it at the end as an optional argument as a convenience.  OCaml features the list as the last argument also as a convenience, as partial application makes it easy to write something like a `sum` function.

```ml
let sum = List.fold_left (+) 0
```

Rather than:

```ml
let sum lst = List.fold_left (+) 0 lst
```